# Assign variable value of object if not nil

Tags: ruby

I'm getting "Called id for nil.." error when I try the assignment below:

```
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0].id
```

What I would like to do is assign

```
@selected = nil if @items_design.items_categories[0].id == nil
```

I tried this:

```
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0].id || nil
```

and a couple of other attempts but no luck. Same error every time.

Comment: and if not `nil`..then ? Also confused about the question. Give the full error stack.

Comment: if it's not nil then I would like it be the value of @items_design.items_categories[0].id

Comment: On which you want to check `nil` value test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is telling you at @items_design.items_categories[0] is nil.  How about this:

```
@selected = 
  if @items_design.items_categories[0]
    @items_design.items_categories[0].id
  else
    nil
  end
```

Or this:

```
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0] ? @items_design.items_categories[0].id : nil
```

Edit: Adding another option from comments which is an even sweeter approach (thanks Daniël!):

```
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0] && @items_design.items_categories[0].id
```

Comment: I like the first option more, it's an awesome Rubyism.  The latter is a little "meh", since ternaries are gross.

Comment: I don't agree, ternary statements are nice and short :). Though that last one can be shortened too `@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0] && @items_design.items_categories[0].id`. If the first part is `nil`, that will be the result of the expression.

Comment: Thanks, brain farting I tried the second solution also but forgot to remove .id from the first part of the ternary. Couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: Nice Daniel!  I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is @items_design.items_categories[0] is nil. So you could try this

```
@selected = nil
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0].id unless @items_design.items_categories[0].nil
```

Comment: `if X not nil` is not valid syntax. You can do `unless X.nil?` or `if not X.nil?`

Comment: Thats the problem when using Ruby and python together :) Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the object `@items_design.items_categories[0]` itself isn't `nil` before sending the `id` message to that object. That's why your "like to do" version won't work, as it still sends the `id` message to an object that winds up being `nil`. This would work

```
@selected = nil if @items_design.items_categories[0].nil?
```

but it still isn't quite what you want. Try something like these:

```
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0].nil? ? nil : @items_design.items_categories[0].id
```

or

```
if @items_design.items_categories[0].nil?
  @selected = nil
else
  @selected = @items_design.items_categories[0].id
end
```

Your second attempt

```
@selected = @items_design.items_categories[0].id || nil
```

isn't working because you always send the `id` message to the array result, even if it is nil.

Comment: We could DRY up your third example by placing the assignment outside the ```if``` block.

Comment: Sure. But I thought the OP would benefit from code that was as straightforward as possible. The Ruby idioms then follow. I like Daniel's version and the ternary one.